# Large PDF sizes but less quality

Tags: pdf, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I'm organizing a large amount of PDFs, some of which need to be inverted, or have their contrast adjusted. But when I use `convert` to modify a PDF, the new file size become much bigger than the original file size, using the `density` and `quality` command to achieve the original quality. A typical command looks like this:

```
convert -density 300 OrignalPDF.pdf -quality 100 -negate NewPDF.pdf
```

This results in a pdf that looks very nearly as sharp as the original, but when switching between the two (with the original inverted within the pdf viewer's settings (qpdfview)), one notices that the new one seems *very slightly* shrunken and that all the lines become slightly thicker/bolder. Obviously this isn't too bad, but shouldn't I be able to invert the colors with almost no noticeable changes?

This slight change becomes even more ridiculous when one notices the size disparity: the original image was 276 KB and the modified file is 28 MB. That's more than 100 times larger! Given that I have hundreds of PDFs, out of which more than 20 or 30 need to be (custom) modified, how can I keep the total size near the original total size, while retaining quality?

Comment: Can you select text in the modified PDFs? Most likely not, because the file size sounds very much as if the document got turned into images. May I suggest to consider Acrobat for such conversions…

Comment: @MaxWyss The files were scanned images to begin with, given to me in pdf format. I'd like to form a pdf of all of the files at the end.

Answer (score 2):

Imagemagick's [documentation](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/formats/#pdf) says:

> *However the reading of these formats is very complicated, as they are full computer languages designed specifically to generate a printed page on high quality laser printers. This is well beyond the scope of ImageMagick, and so it relies on a specialized delegate program known as "ghostscript" to read, and convert Postscript and PDF pages to a raster image.*

So, ImageMagick converts PDF to raster image first and then it makes a simple PDF from this raster image. And the output PDF is unsearchable, contains no vectors, no hidden text etc but just the page wide raster image. But PDF (and PostScript) is not just a set of images but a set of commands, text, vectors, fonts, and even a sub-scripts inside (to calculate output color, for example). PDF is more like an application rather than a static image.

Anywa, I suppose you may have 2 types of input PDF files:

1. with page-wide images inside (for example, scanned documents). You should process 1st type only using imagemagick. This type of files will be converted into the nearly the same file size.
2. with pure text and vectors inside (for example, PDF invoices). This type of files should **not** be processed using imagemagick as the conversion damages the input file (and finally increases the output file size). If you still need to adjust contrast or compression of images inside files of this type then consider using the [ghostscript](http://www.ghostscript.com/) directly, check this [tutorial](http://zeroset.mnim.org/2014/07/24/change-image-compression-in-pdf-files-with-ghostscript/).

Comment: Unfortunately, my files are all of the first type: scanned, full page images, and `convert` still bloats the size. Any hints for that?

Comment: That makes the solution easier! Seems like you just need to find the best compression, see -compress option and  http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php?#compress

Comment: Just make sure that the compression you choose is not damaging the input (check on 2-3 files). Lossless compressions (Lossless,LZW, RLE, ZIP, BZIP) giving larger files while Fax, JPEG may significantly reduce the file size but make sure they are not damaging the text (JPEG adds the blur around text and makes OCR much harder then)

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that when I have a chance!

Comment: OK, I tried all of the lossless options, and the best was ZIP, which gave me a factor of only 10x file size bloat. Still, what am I doing that increases the size? Were my files already compressed with a lossy algorithm? (If so, how can I tell?)

Comment: Try to open PDF file in the Notepad and search for the "/Filter" string. It will contain the filter type next to it, like "/Filter /FlateDecode" for ZIP like compression. See all available compression types in PDF Reference 1.7 ( https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_reference_1-7.pdf) at page 67 (TABLE 3.5 Standard filters)

Comment: @numeri please let us know which option worked for you the best! so could edit the answer

Comment: My original PDF file contained about 10 instances of the `/Filter` type `JBig2Decode`, one `FLateDecode`, and one `[FLateDecode DCTDecode]`. (That PDF is only one page, with only one image on it, if that helps.) I haven't tried any of the lossy algorithms yet, but like I said, out of the lossless algorithms, ZIP brought the size down by 10x.

Comment: @Numeri thank you for sharing this! You may want to try JBIG in the output too, JBIG is the lossless compressio too.